# How we can fetch data from an API in node js

Tags: node.js

How we can fetch data from an API in node js. I am very hard to retrieve data from an API. Please let me know how i can solve this problem

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. So is not ask anything and get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js has a built in request module for that, you can find a tutorial for that [here](https://stackabuse.com/the-node-js-request-module/)

Comment: Thank sir for helping me out

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for your.

```
const request = require('request');
    const options = {
        url: 'https://www.reddit.com/r/funny.json',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
            'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'
        }
    };
    
    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        let json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json);
    });
```

Comment: Thank sir for helping me out